# How can I see the "original mail" on yahoo, like gmail?

Tags: email, yahoo-mail

I have a mailbox on yahoo and I would like to view some email original source like gmail's option, "show original mail".

Is there an option like that in yahoo? I couldn't find it.

Comment: To those abusing the tags with **belongs-on-** stop it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-tags

Comment: webapps.stackexchange,com

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/yL1Z5RY.png

Answer (score 1):

[**YPOPs!**](http://ypopsemail.com/) is an application that provides POP3 and SMTP access to Yahoo! Mail.

> YPOPs! is a free open source software
>   that provides POP3 and SMTP access to
>   Yahoo! Mail. You can use your
>   favourite email client, be it Outlook,
>   Thunderbird, or whatever else you like
>   and connect to Yahoo! Mail seamlessly.

Comment: might not apply anymore

Answer (score 1):

Click the ... menu at the bottom of the message and click "View raw message"

**added by barlop**

as of may 2021

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's more of an application use question than programming. However if Yahoo! don't provide a facility, you can fetch the mail from Yahoo! using POP3 and read the full mail in any email client that supports showing the original source, or code up a client/script to fetch it.

However POP3 access in Yahoo! is limited to paying customers.

[How to read Yahoo! Mail in an email reader](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/classic/mailplus/pop/pop-35.html)

Comment: You don't need to pay for Yahoo POP3 access. Read my answer below.

Comment: now limited.. it wasn't before

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the full message headers, you can use `Actions -> Full Header` to see them.

Comment: as of 2021 they changed it